# Synchronizing JMS Message Queue and JDBC transaction- Is Transaction proxy needed

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

We need to persist message from a JMS Queue to a database in a transaction ensuring that JMS message is not acknowledged in case any error is thrown during DB persist. 
Based on the solution provided here- [Transaction handling while using message driven channel adapter & service activator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451728/transaction-handling-while-using-message-driven-channel-adapter-service-activa)
Below is the approach I arrived at

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    connection-factory="sConnectionFactory"
    destination-name="emsQueue"
    acknowledge="transacted" channel="jmsInChannel"/>

<int:channel id=" jmsInChannel " />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a datasource -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

    <bean id="sconnectionFactory"       class="org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="project.TestConnectionFactory">

            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="synchedLocalTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Please confirm if the understanding is correct. Also, have the below queries

1. Is the TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy necessary in this scenario
2. JMS Queue and JDBC are two separate transactional resources. Is injecting jdbc transaction manager into JMS adapter as shown in this example equivalent to using a ChainedTransactionManager(chaining JMS Transaction Mananger and JDBC transaction manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy`, please, consult its JavaDocs:

```
 * Proxy for a target CCI {@link javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory}, adding
 * awareness of Spring-managed transactions. Similar to a transactional JNDI
 * ConnectionFactory as provided by a Java EE server.
 *
 * <p>Data access code that should remain unaware of Spring's data access support
 * can work with this proxy to seamlessly participate in Spring-managed transactions.
 * Note that the transaction manager, for example the {@link CciLocalTransactionManager},
 * still needs to work with underlying ConnectionFactory, <i>not</i> with this proxy.
```

I'm not sure how is that related to your request about JMS+DB transaction, but I think you should worry about transaction manager which supports both those transactional resources.

For this purpose Spring suggests `JtaTransactionManager` for XA transactions.
Or you can consider to use `ChainedTransactionManager` based on the Dave Syer article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

**UPDATE**

If local transaction are fine for you, you really can go ahead with the `TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy` and its `synchedLocalTransactionAllowed` to `true`. And, of course, use that `DataSourceTransactionManager` directly from the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`.

Otherwise you have to go with the `ChainedTransactionManager`. This solution really adds some overhead over the first `TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy`-based one.

Comment: I went through best-jms-db project from Dave's article. It injects a DataSourceTransactionManager bean into jms:listener-container(I injected this transactionManager into message driven channel adapter which is based on Message Listener container) but does not use any JmsTransactionManager. I cannot see any explicit chaining in this project or JTA Transaction manager. How is the JMS Transaction Resource and JDBC transaction resource being synchronized in this example.

Comment: Please, take a look into my UPDATE in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, can you also suggest the difference between the two approaches- is the local transaction 1PC(so need to handle duplicate messages) while ChainedTransactionManager 2PC

Comment: No, `ChainedTransactionManager` is 1PC as well. You have 2PC only in case of XA transactions and JTA-similar transaction manager. Only the problem with `ChainedTransactionManager` that you will have to perform several (almost independent) transactions. Your are just happy that there is that `TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy` for JMS. Some other system might not have such a solution, so  `ChainedTransactionManager` will be an answer.

Comment: ok, is there any other drawback you see in the TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy approach besides the duplicate message handling part. 
Also, can a similar TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryApproach be used in case we need to synchronize two JMS transaction resources as in my earlier question-[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441359/should-jmstransactionmanager-be-used-when-persisting-from-one-jms-queue-to-anoth
)

Comment: M-m-m. No, I don't have any experience with the `TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy`. And yes, I think that one ca be used in that your scenario. Just because you are still there with JMS, therefore one `JmsTransactionManager` and another `ConnectionFactory` is wrapped to this proxy.